# Why "likelihood is proportional to the probability of the data given the hypothesis"

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

In [Etz](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2515245917744314), there is "likelihood is proportional to the probability of the data given the hypothesis" and "L(H) = K × P(D|H)", are there more detailed explanations to understand it? Some related question are [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444781/definition-of-likelihood-in-bayesian-statistics) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554041/is-it-accurate-to-call-pdh-the-likelihood-in-bayesian-inference), thanks!

Comment: It is impossible to understand such a phrase as "proportional to the data given the hypothesis" unless you're told that it means proportional as a function of the hypothesis, with the data fixed.